# Thunderbolt 3: Can I get "Power Delivery" *output* on a TB3 hub/chip?

Tags: usb-c, thunderbolt, usb-pd

tl;dr: read title. Thunderbolt 3 hubs often have a "power delivery" port (alt: usb-c port that may support usb-pd). Are they input only, or also output, or 'maybe, good luck getting the specs'? Is there some way to get 70 watts power output from a hub connected to a TB3 port?

====

I have a project I'm designing, and one of my needs is a thunderbolt 3 hub that (among others things) allows me to pull power *from* it (I think about 72 watts?). It was only after looking at several ads that I realized they all show power going *into* those power delivery ports, not out of them.

I'm a bit at a loss. I know that supporting PD is an optional part of the USB-C spec, iirc, so I can't trust USB-C ports on TB3 hubs to necessarily support USB-PD either, right?

For my project, I need a hub that

1. Has two video outputs (preferably two HDMI ports, but just need two independent video outputs)
2. Can supply about 70 watts of power output (so, probably via PD) that it pulls *from the thunderbolt port*.

Is this feasible/reasonable/possible?

(Btw, I really don't *need* it to be in the form of a finished 'hub' product--if it's possible to get a raw chip that has those ports on them, that would be even better, I just don't know how to look for such things.)

Answer (score 2):

You might face difficulties finding a hub that can fulfill your requirements due to the power limitations of USB-C/TB3/TB4 ports on laptops.

**TB3 ports** typically have a **power output limit of 15W**. Consequently, hubs connected to these ports cannot supply more than 15W to peripherals unless they have an external power source too.

The power output by a USB-C port on a device is referred to as "bus power". Here's a brief summary of the power output for different port types:

- USB-A (2.0, 3.0) ports usually **output** 5W (5V at 1A).
- USB-C ports typically **output** either 7.5W (5V at 1.5A) or 15W (5V at 3A).
- Thunderbolt 3 ports generally **output** 15W (5V at 3A).
- USB-C ports implementing USB-PD 3.0 can **receive** up to 100W (20V at 5A).
- USB-C ports implementing USB-PD 3.1 can **receive** up to 240W (48V at 5A).

Unfortunately, marketing materials seldom mention the output power. You should consult your device's specifications (provided by the manufacturer) to find the output power limit for each port. Depending on the USB controller configuration, the limits mentioned above might be shared across multiple ports.

If you want to power displays, there are several excellent portable USB-C monitors available. The "LG Gram +View (16")" uses a single USB-C cable for power and video signal. [According to LG](https://www.lg.com/us/support/product/lg-16MQ70.ADSU1), it requires 7.5W of power and should be compatible with any TB3 port, or USB-C port supporting "DisplayPort Alt Mode".

The reason higher output USB-C/TB3/TB4 ports are not common in laptops is due to space and heat constraints. For example, Apple's power adapters increase in size with higher output capacity. Gallium Nitride (GaN) adapters offer greater space efficiency, but the demand for integrating them into devices like laptops is currently low.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt 3 hubs only have the ability to *input* power to supported devices; it is not reversible. They cannot output power.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm converging on realizing. There's no way to output 70 watts from a laptop, as far as I can tell, right?

Also, is there any difference between USB-C power delivery and Thunderbolt 3 power delivery?

Comment: When you say PD can only act as an input, though, *period*, that seems incorrect though--isn't the USB-C plug on a USB-C charger for a laptop a USB-C/USB-PD *output*? For some reason, no one puts those in laptops (to clarify, I don't mean ultrabooks that charge on their usb-c ports, but heavy machines with an alternate charging system like a Dell Precision, Dell G5, Thinkpad P1, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

**HUB or DOCKING STATION** ?

A **HUB** will **draw power** from your PC in order to power the peripherals. I doubt any laptop would have 72W of extra power budget to deliver to a hub, but it might be doable with a tower PC.
Some hubs though have a pass-through charging UBS-C connector on which to connect your power brick, so you need to connect only one cable to your laptop: in that case it will **provide** power.
Here's a [random example hub with pass through charging] [1]

A **Docking Station** has its own power brick and is designed to **output** Power to your laptop or whatever is there to draw power.
The TB /USB-C spec limits are 100W, so you should be able to find something suitable.
Here is [a random example with 87WPD][2]

**Getting the chips** probably will cost you much more than dissecting an existing hub / docking station, unless you have to buy hundreds of them

[1] : [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07ZVKTP53/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_imm_t1_1HGJPY4NVETSXC02VF7P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZVKTP53)

[2] : [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07CZPV8DF/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_imm_t1_Q0EAP2B6XT5W6QV91KZV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZPV8DF)

Comment: A hub, in your nomenclature. A Y540 laptop only allows 5v 3a out of its USB-C port, but it has a huge 240w charging brick. In theory, I think less than 200 watts of that gets used at peak by the computer (comparable laptops, like the G5 5590, feature 180 watt power bricks--numbers from recent memory, though worth double checking). In that case, in theory many watts could be available for PD. I specifically want a hub that has it downstream, but I think I have realized since doing further research that basically no laptop allows the PD *output*, they only accept pd *input*, which wasn't clear